# replacing sprite images on a character

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm a little new to Unity and here's a template i'm working on (here: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/2d-platformer-11228) and I'm unsure of how to change their sprite animations to my own sprite animations.
Can anyone give any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: The Unity website actually has a very good tutorial section.  Head over to their [Animation Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/animation) and watch videos 1 through 4 under the "Controlling Animation" section.  I am certain all of your questions will be answered once you finish those.

Comment: Before watching the animation tutorials i mentioned above, you might also want to watch their [sprite tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/2d-game-creation), specifically videos 3 through 6 under the "Unity for 2D" section.  If you still have questions after watching these videos then I recommend coming back here and editing your question to something more specific.

Comment: Thank you for those, but I'm trying to figure out how to switch artwork that they've provided to another set of artwork of my own.

Answer (score 0):

advice:

- if you have your own animations, you can add them to the animation window as sprites, (they should work, if not, check out some tutorials or other forums)
- but if you want to make your own and you are using photoshop, your own custom animations can be created (2d sprite) in the 'timeline section' (window > timeline), its kinda like stop motion, but it is exported into a image sequence. (essentially, you just draw your character and move it onto the timeline where you can repeat the process with new images that have minor changes)
- however, if you are not using photoshop, you may be able to draw your frames (images) and put them together and import them into unity where you can do what i suggested in the first dot point.